# Запрос по совпадению текстового поля которое хранится в виде JSON

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, регулярные-выражения

Есть такая таблица

```
CREATE TABLE localhost.`regexp` (
 id int(11) NOT NULL,
 name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 8192
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

В поле `name` хранится JSON в таком виде

```
1|{"is_equal":["1","2","3"]}
2|{"is_equal":["3"],"is_not_equal":["2"]}
```

Нужна помощь составить запрос на получение данных в которых поле `name` содержит в ключе `is_equal` значение (или 1 или 2) к примеру.

Условия:

1)MySql 5.6 нет возможности работать как с JSON;

2)нет возможности поменять субд;

3)как серверный язык использую PHP, но хочу сделать это на стороне базы;

4)про проектирование таблиц говорить не стоит, так сложилось исторически, менять структуру нельзя;

На данный момент есть:

```
 SELECT * FROM localhost.`regexp` WHERE name REGEXP 'is_equal(1|2)'
```

но он ищет  совпадения и в `is_equal` и в `is_not_equal`, а мне нужно что бы только в `is_equal`.

Comment: Текущее регулярное выражение что-то находит? Или Вы просто написали что-то, чтобы было?

Comment: Если есть возможность обновить MySQL до версии **5.7**, у вас появится возможность [полноценно работать с JSON](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html).

Comment: Условия:

1)MySql 5.6 нет возможности работать как с JSON;

Comment: SELECT * FROM localhost.`regexp` WHERE name REGEXP 'is_equal(1|2)'
но он ищет совпадения и в is_equal и в is_not_equal, а мне нужно что бы только в is_equal

Comment: `is_equal(1|2)` соответствует всего двух строкам:  `is_equal1` и `is_equal2` . Ни первого, ни второго образца нет в приведенном JSON. Это регулярное выражение не может ни с чем совпадать, если Вы привели верные данные. Хотя, может быть я заблуждаюсь и в mysql какая-то иная интерпретация регулярных выражений, но вряд ли.

Comment: Да прошу прощения вы правы, не тот запрос выложил

Comment: SELECT * FROM localhost.`regexp` WHERE name REGEXP '(1|2)'

Answer (score 0):

до 5.7 есть возможность работать с json с помощью udf ф-ий, которые написала Света Смирнова
http://www.slideshare.net/SvetaSmirnova/json-ud-fsru

Comment: что-то новенькое, спасибо